# Babel module resolver doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, eslintrc

I configured babel-plugin-module-resolver with eslint in my node project. This is my eslintrc.

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "newline-per-chained-call": "off",
    "indent": ["warn", 2],
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", {"warn": "none"}],
    "max-len": ["warn", 150],
    "no-console": 1,
    "object-curly-newline": ["warn", {
      "ObjectPattern": { "multiline": true },
      "ExportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 4 }
    }]
  }
}
```

This is my babelrc file.

```
{   
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "constants": "./constants",
          "database": "./database",
          "library": "./library",
          "mappers": "./mappers",
          "middleware": "./middleware",
          "models": "./models",
          "repositories": "./repositories",
          "routes": "./routes",
          "services": "./services",
          "utils": "./utils"
        }
      }
    ]
  ] 
}
```

Now in my project the paths are working properly like this.

```
import User from 'models/user.model';
import UserRepository from 'repositories/user.repository';
```

But I have the following issues.
When I click on an import, it doesn't go to the definition. 
IntelliSense are not working.

What am I doing here with these plugins? I want ot have intellisense and go to definition(navigating) feature.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, did u solve this?

Comment: Yes. Are you working with node or react?

Comment: React Native which requires nodeJs

Answer (score 1):

@shashika, you have to set up the **jsconfig.json** for the javascript project, **tsconfig.json** for the typescript project to make your custom-defined path go to the respective files definition,

Example:

```
    {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "paths": {
         "@/*": ["./src/*"],
         "@util/*": ["./util/*"],
       },
    }
```

Comment: Should be marked as the accepted solution. 
Adding aliases to babel (babelrc or babel.config) will only inform babel during transpiling that the paths are in this or that location. However, VScode by itself knows nothing about babel config files, so it will need some information about those aliased paths as well - as shown by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For intellisense autocompletion to work in Visual Studio code so it takes you to the module when clicking on the import, you have to add the modules under `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` under compiler options as mentioned on the documentation for [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#editors-autocompletion). Keep in mind that `paths` are relative to `baseUrl`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"],
      "test/*": ["test/*"],
      "underscore": ["lodash"]
    }
  }
}
```